# Python 3.8 Raise matrix to power of -1 results in inf

Tags: python, numpy

I have a simple matrix in Python:

```
[[1134.01    0.  ]
 [   0.   1134.01]]
```

And I need to raise it to the power of -1.  I have tried

```
mat**-1 and mat = pow(mat, -1)
```

Both methods give me an infinity in the 0 place (I get it you can't divide by zero). The result looks like:

```
[[0.00088183        inf]
 [       inf 0.00088183]]
```

And it gives me this warning because it is trying to divide by zero:

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in reciprocal
```

So other than manually replacing the inf with 0 or adding a small value to my original matrix, is there a way to tell python not to produce the inf and put a 0 instead?

Comment: It would help if you could clarify whether you are trying to take the inverse of the matrix, sometimes notated a `A ** -1` or you want to raise the individual elements of the matrix to the power of `-1` — what `A ** -1 ` actually does. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.linalg.inv` instead.

```
>>> np.linalg.inv(np.array([[1134.01, 0], [0, 1134.01]]))
array([[0.00088183, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.00088183]])
```

Comment: It didn't occur to me that they may want the matrix inversion. I assumed they were looking for element-wise power operation (which is what `mat**-1` does). It's only a coincidence that they have the same result here.

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood what mat ** -1 was doing.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you actually use a matrix:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1134.01, 0.],
    [0., 1134.01]
])

print(np.matrix(a) ** -1)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYuxCsQgEAX7/YpXajCi5Np8SbDYLhaaZeNB/Hoj3E0zMDDS23nVbYxc5NKG@i3SwTeqEDH2ac@q3M1BmBwxbh8fokPwyf1S8A7/nChZItFcm5ln4ab5MWyxLFijHeMF)):

```
[[0.00088183 0.        ]
 [0.         0.00088183]]
```

Comment: Worth noting that this appear to take the matrix inverse not element-wise power. Compare with a test that shows the distinction: `a = np.array([[1, 2.],[2., 3]])`

Comment: @Mark Well, yes, that's what matrix power means. One shouldn't even think of "element-wise" there.

Comment: Sure, but it's not clear that's what the OP wants. `mat**-1` is element wise power, `pow()` is element-wise, `numpy.power()` is element-wise. They picked a poor example where the inverse and element-wise power are the same.

Comment: @Mark I think it's clear. They say matrix power. And they complain about getting element-wise inversion instead (and they're **not** the same in their example).

Comment: Their *desired result* is the same.

Comment: @Mark You said *"They picked a poor example where the inverse and element-wise power are the same"*. That is not true. Element-wise power results in what they got. What you're talking about and do in your answer isn't element-wise power. I guess you could call it "nonzero-element-wise power" (most concise reasonable name I can think of).

Comment: Sure, "nonzero-element-wise-power" sounds like what they are asking for: `So other than manually replacing the inf with 0 or adding a small value to my original matrix, is there a way to tell python not to produce the inf and put a 0 instead?`
Which is why I asked for clarification. Not sure why you are going to the mat over this, it wouldn't be the first time a person asked for something using the wrong terminology.

Comment: @Mark As far as I can see, you keep dragging me to the mat :-)